# Getting BeautifulSoup to catch tags in a non-case-sensitive way

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup, case-insensitive

I want to catch some tags with BeautifulSoup: Some `<p>` tags, the `<title>` tag, some `<meta>` tags. But I want to catch them regardless of their case; I know that some sites do meta like this: `<META>` and I want to be able to catch that.

I noticed that BeautifulSoup is case-sensitive by default. How do I catch these tags in a non-case-sensitive way?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use [soup.findAll](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html#The%20basic%20find%20method:%20findAll%28name,%20attrs,%20recursive,%20text,%20limit,%20**kwargs%29) which should match case-insensitively:

```
import BeautifulSoup

html = '''<html>
<head>
<meta name="description" content="Free Web tutorials on HTML, CSS, XML" /> 
<META name="keywords" content="HTML, CSS, XML" /> 
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(html)
for x in soup.findAll('meta'):
    print x
```

Result:

```
<meta name="description" content="Free Web tutorials on HTML, CSS, XML" />
<meta name="keywords" content="HTML, CSS, XML" />
```

Comment: Ah, so BeautifulSoup converts all tags to lowercase? What about attributes? And does that mean I can also use `find` instead of `findAll` and it would still be case-insensitive?

Comment: @cool-RR: Yes find works in a similar way to findAll. The case-sensitivity depends on what you are doing though.

Comment: Okay, now I tried and it does convert attributes to lowercase.

Answer (score 2):

BeautifulSoup standardises the parse tree on input. It converts tags to lower-case. You don't have anything to worry about IMO.

Comment: Unfortunately it does the same for case sensitive markups like XML too.